# can't redirect method from ajax method to aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, ajax

I have following code in my CenterDetail.aspx page

```
function myFunction(id) {
    console.log(2);
    var myindex = window.ContentPlaceHolder1_ddCountryId.selectedIndex;
    console.log(myindex);
    var selectedName = window.ContentPlaceHolder1_ddCountryId.options[myindex].text;
    console.log(selectedName);
    var loc = window.location.href;
    console.log(loc);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: loc + "/BindState",
        data: { id : id },
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

and following method is in my code behind file.

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string BindState(int id)
    {
        var states = new StateProvinceCollection().Where(StateProvince.Columns.CountryId = Convert.ToString(id), true).ToList();

        string tag = "<select id='StateProvinceId' name='StateProvinceName'>";
        tag += "<option value=''>select</option>";
        foreach (var item in states)
        {
            tag += "<option value='" + item.StateProvinceId + "'>" + item.StateProvinceName + "</option>";
        }
        tag += "</select>";
        return tag;
    }
```

everything is still it show http://musicclass/Account/Management/Center/CenterDetail.aspx/BindState 404 not found error.

Comment: Where do you want to re-direct to? I mean do you have the URL to redirect?

Comment: ** url: loc + "/BindState", ** this is my url

Comment: Why do you want to redirect to that URL? That URL is for a `WebMethod` and not for an aspx page. You can only redirect to aspx page or an html page like `abc.aspx` or `abc.html` or `abc.htm`.

Comment: i want to get data from the method which is written above.. so i wrote ajax method in which u can see url section and the method BindState is in my code behind file.

Comment: ajax is called but in ajax it stops at its url section. by showing following error:  http://musicclass/Account/Management/Center/CenterDetail.aspx/BindState 404 not found error.

Comment: sorry but still it is not happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100213/discussion-between-sadhana-and-sunil).